# Can't set a default value on spinner

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to retrieved the status value from the database and set it on a spinner.
I am doing the following but I am getting   `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Cancelled"`

```
spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(job.getStatus()));
```

```
   JobRepository jobRepository = new JobRepository(a.getApplication());
        VehicleRepository vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository(a.getApplication());
        jobRepository.find(UUID.fromString(jobId)).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), jc -> {
            vehicleRepository.findByJob(fromString(jobId)).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), vehicle -> {
                Job job = jc.job;
                Customer customer = jc.customer;
                status.setText(job.getStatus());
                customerName.setText(customer.getName());
                postcode.setText(job.getPostcode());
                notesView.setEms(4);
                notesView.setMaxLines(5);
                notesView.setText(job.getNotes());
                phoneNum.setText(customer.getTel());
                emailAdd.setText(customer.getEmail());
                emailAdd.setMaxLines(2);

                spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(job.getStatus()));

                if (job.getUpdatedAt() != null) {
                    lastUpdate.setText(sdf.format(job.getUpdatedAt()));
                }
```

Comment: from your exception alone, you're trying to parse `Cancelled` as a number, and it fails to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to ensure `job.getStatus()` it's an `Int` since [setSelection(int position](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner#setSelection(int,%20boolean)) is waiting you to pass an `Int` and `Cancelled` can not be converted to an `Int` even if you use `Integer.parseInt()`.

Also I don't see where you set the items, so perhaps is a good idea to set items and then do the `setSelection()` otherwise it won't work neither.